# Unable to Install PythonMagick on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, imagemagick

I have installed Python 2.7.13 on my Windows 10 machine.
I went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick and downloaded both the 32 and 64bit versions:

```
PythonMagick‑0.9.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
PythonMagick‑0.9.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

I ran the following command from commandline (admin permissions):

```
pip install PythonMagick‑0.9.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
```

I get the following error:

```
PythonMagick‑0.9.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have tried with both the 32 and 64bit versions of Python 2.7, as well as both the 32 and 64bit versions of PythonMagick.

I tried downloading the Zip from ImageMagick, but the install made no sense to me (there is a reason I use Windows, not *nix)

Answer (score 1):

By using the older WHL I was able to get PythonMagick installed and working.

```
PythonMagick‑0.9.10‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```